# "Lost challenge" clearly showing a reversal of expectations

Tags: phrase-requests

In a scenario where the conventional thinking that when A competes with B, A would win / get the upper hand, but where  last findings in date show that B has the upper hand, I'm trying to phrase this idea in a concise way that highlights the logic:

> The challenge was lost by A.

While this is probably acceptable, I don't feel the reversal of expectations has been conveyed clearly.

Comment: The result you seek has not been done at all. You need to phrase the setup implying the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the criterion that determines conventional thinking. Is it a mathematical rule (speed of computation of electronic machines)? (1) Is it a statistical rule (boxing relative to the age of the fighters)? (2) Is it a rule of approximate evaluation (horse races)? (3)

Here are some possibilities, but even if typical, they are by no means the only ones.

- A has *unexplicably* failed against B (1)
- *in spite of statistical odds* A has failed against B (2)
- A was beaten by B *against all odds* (3)

Answer (score 1):

The OP mentions "conventional thinking" and "I'm trying to phrase this idea in a concise way that highlights the logic" for competitors/rivals. I suggest:

> B came from behind to win over (the favorite) A.

**come from behind** (idiom)

> Also, come up from behind. Advance from the rear or from a losing
> position, as in ... *The polls say our candidate is coming up from
> behind.* This idiom, which originated in horse racing was first
> transferred to scores in various sports and later to more general use.
> [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/come-from-behind)

> Win after lagging [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/come_from_behind)

> THE PRESIDENT. ... In New Hampshire, we **came from behind** and won, and
> I think we are going to do the same thing here in Florida. [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Weekly_Compilation_of_Presidential_Docum/aIY5B5OMxtIC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=came%20%20from%20behind%20and%20won&pg=PA304&printsec=frontcover).

> It's human nature to love those kinds of edge-of-your-seat,
> **come-from-behind** photo finishes, especially unexpected wins where the underdog or Cinderella team carries the day. [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Mind_Sword/u0cIsfblLUMC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22come%20from%20behind%22%20unexpected%20win&pg=PT149&printsec=frontcover).

Answer (score 0):

One way to describe these kinds of events that defy expectation is to call them an "upset", eg "the loss against a weaker team was a major upset for our team".